# Control register of magnetometer in MPU-9250 reseting itself

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, stm32, i2c, imu

I want to read magnetometer outputs from the **MPU-9250** sensor ([Datasheet](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf), [Register Map](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/5/5/0/MPU-9250-Register-Map.pdf)) but the **CNTL1 Register (0x0A)** of the magnetometer resets for certain values. I configured the sensor properly so that I bypass slave adress to read the magnetometer and I am succesfull in reading the **WHO_AM_I** register of the Magnetometer.

The problem occurs when I try to configure the magnetometer by writing **0x16** (16-bit outputs, continuous mode 2) or **0x12** (16-bit outputs, continuous mode 1) to the **CNTL1 Register (0x0A)**. When I write **0x12** and read back, I get **0x02** and when I write **0x16** and read back I get **0x00**.

```
data[0] = 0x00;
/* Writing to the CNTL1_AD register (Power-Down Mode)*/
result = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, MagnetometerAddress, CNTL1_AD, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
if ( result != HAL_OK ) {
    strcpy((char*)buf, "Error Writing I2C!\n");
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*) buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

HAL_Delay(100);

data[0] = 0x12;
/* Writing to the CNTL1_AD register (Continuous Mode 1 and 16-bit output)*/
result = HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(&hi2c1, MagnetometerAddress, CNTL1_AD, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
if ( result != HAL_OK ) {
    strcpy((char*)buf, "Error Writing I2C!\n");
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*) buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

HAL_Delay(100);

/* Reading from the CNTL1_AD register */
result = HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(&hi2c1, MagnetometerAddress, CNTL1_AD, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
if ( result != HAL_OK ) {
    strcpy((char*)buf, "Error Writing I2C!\n");
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buf, strlen((char*) buf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}
```

Writing 0x12 read back as 0x02 and writing 0x16 reads back 0x00. I don't know why it's reseting the 4th bit or why it's reseting Mode 2 and not Mode 1. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: This question was also posted to https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/hhkba3/control_register_of_magnetometer_in_mpu9250/ and has an answer there.

Comment: It’s not answered yet. They said I needed to power down the magnetometer to change modes but it’s exactly what I did in the beginning.